# How to default to searching for files using Visual Studio's New Search Experience?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In the "New Search Experience", you can search across Files/Types/Members.

[image]

However, 99.9% of the time, I only want to search for files.  Everything else is just noise to me.

Is there a way to bring up this dialog with "files" button pre-selected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open it using, Ctrl+Shift+T, and it will default to files.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+T ' didn't do anything in the IDE.  I had to go into Options/Keybaord and map it to Edit.GoToFile.

Comment: @AngryHacker  My VS2022 install is pretty much a default install and the shortcut is how I open it. I did notice if you hover any of the three options (files, types, and members) the option's shortcut key(s) are displayed in the tooltip, in case anyone has the same issue as you or happens to have a different shortcut mapped.